# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I received this error a week ago on a Visual Studio 2010 project. I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb) thread and it had the correct solution. I had to download the 2007 access database engine and I no longer received this error.

This week, I am doing a new project and received the exact same error. On the old project, I did not. I uninstalled the program that was downloaded to originally get it to work. Tried both projects, neither one worked, which is what should happen. Restarted computer, installed program again, then restarted computer again. I tried the new project where it wasn't working and it still didn't work. Tried the old one, it still worked.

So I went back to the thread and noticed that in step two he says "in VS click add data source, follow the wizard." I had not done this to get it to work with my first project. So I tried it out, but I still receive the error. Odds are, I didn't do it correctly, so if I get help here, that would be great. I will detail out the steps I originally did where it didn't work.

1. Go to data and then add new data source
2. Select database, hit next
3. Select dataset, hit next
4. New connection > Browse for database file > blank username and password > Hit ok > hit next
5. A prompt appears saying "The connection you selected uses a local data file that is not in the current project. Would you like to copy the file to your project and modify the connection? If you copy the data file to your project, it will be copied to the project's output directory each time you run the application. Press F1 for information on controlling this behavior." > Select Yes
6. "Do you want to save the connection string to the application configuration file?" > Yes, save file as DBConnectionString > select next
7. "What database objects do you want to use in your dataset?" > I selected the only two tables that I am using in this project > finish

I would just like to say that for my first, working project, the database is just in my folder, not actually added in the project and it works. For step 5 above, I have selected yes and no for adding the datafile to my project. Either way, it doesn't work and even if I say no, it still adds the files to my project.

Sorry for the long response. Thought it would be helpful to have all the detail. Any help appreciated. 
5.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why, but it is working now.

I removed the process of adding the data source; I didn't need it. I have an application configuration file that configurations the settings and such. I removed this code, copied the code from my old one, then saved it in the new project. I saved the project. I ran it and now the problem was gone.

The code was exactly the same, so I don't understand why. It appears though that there was a problem with my SQL statement. It's as if the error message for this wasn't being displayed and for some reason the error message mentioned above was instead. I don't understand it, but it works now and I did virtually nothing.

If you have no idea what config file I'm referring to, the code for mine is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="DBConnectionString"
         value = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Password = ; User ID = ; Data Source = "/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with MDAC and build targets, for example, if you are on a 64bit machine and your project targets x86, you must install the MDAC for x86, but if you target Any CPU, then you need the x64 version installed.  If your project was never built, there may be an issue with the system determining which version of MDAC is going to be required.  When in doubt, you probably should just install both the x86 and x64 versions on your machine, just to be safe.  MDAC 2010 can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).